# Android/Kotlin Material Button Group default selection

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I have a Material Button Toggle Group in a Fragment layout (with single selection and selection required), but on load of my app I want one of the button to *already* be selected. I thought adding this to my Main Activity `onCreate()` would have done the trick (the id of my button is `paletteA`):

```
paletteA.isPressed = true
```

but instead my app just crashes on loadtime and no errors are displayed in the Run window. Feels like something is not loading in time or is null, even though all of my Fragments have already been loaded in, etc, and this is the very last thing in my `onCreate()`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` widget has an XML attribute named `app:checkedButton` that can be used to load a button in the group as checked.

To set a particular button inside the `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` to load as checked by default, pass the id of the button to be checked as the value to the `app:checkedButton` attribute.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        ...
        app:singleSelection="true"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_togglebutton"
        app:checkedButton="@id/activity_main_button2">
```

Comment: !! I spent 20 minutes looking for an attribute with "selected" in the name ... thank you!